# Python3 Classes- Can you change it into a string?

Tags: python, class

I created a class: Hopper
So that first_rabbit=Hopper('Thumper')

```
def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        number_hops=10 
        self.number_hops=number_hops
def __repr__(self):
        return (self.name + str(self.number_hops))
```

However, outside of the class, I use a function: jumping contest(first, second):
Where the parameters would be  rabbits (ie: Hopper('Thumper'))

In that function is there a way to isolate just the name like 'Thumper' so that I can print info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually go one step further in the built in attributes and use the **name** attribute. It would be like this:

```
def __init__(self,name):
    self.__name__=name
    number_hops=10 
    self.number_hops=number_hops
def __repr__(self):
    return self.__name__
```

This would not really do anything differently, but the attribute **name** is there for this purpose, so it is probably best to use it. Alternatively, because you probably want to keep the **repr** that tells you both peices of information, so instead of accessing it by

```
print(rabbit)
```

than you would use

```
print(rabbit.__name__)
```

or just make a second function, like

```
def name(self):
    return self.__name__
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And you can invoke it with

`print(first_rabbit)`

Comment: I think that just replaces the repr

Comment: You asked `is there a way to isolate just the name?`